# Display flex is taking more width than assigned width on a div

Tags: html, css

The div is having some width and the text inside that is dynamically coming from API and it has styles ellipsis. I can't provide the width of the text as the text is completely dynamic and not sure about the text length. Below is the code that explains the issue.

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 130px;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.justify-content-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.table-header__width-ellipses {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100  align-items-center">
      <div class=" d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div>
        <!-- style="width: 110px" ---- is showing correct ellipsis and text fits in the width -->

          <span class="table-header__width-ellipses pl-2">Long text included here </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="header--sort_icon"></div>
        <div class="cursor-pointer cell-header-addcol">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/01/11/21/48/link-6931554_1280.png" alt="menu" width="16" height="16">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100  align-items-center">
      <div class=" d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div>
          <span class="table-header__width-ellipses pl-2">Long text included here </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="header--sort_icon"></div>
        <div class="cursor-pointer cell-header-addcol">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/01/11/21/48/link-6931554_1280.png" alt="menu" width="16" height="16">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div>
```

I am trying to generate content like this for the tabular styles. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work, you should specify the width of the `inline-block` span element.

So add `width: 130px;` to `.table-header__width-ellipses` and use `width: 150px;` for `.container`

**Working Code.**

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.justify-content-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.table-header__width-ellipses {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100  align-items-center">
      <div class=" d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div>
        <!-- style="width: 110px" ---- is showing correct ellipsis and text fits in the width -->

          <span class="table-header__width-ellipses pl-2">Long text included here </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="header--sort_icon"></div>
        <div class="cursor-pointer cell-header-addcol">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/01/11/21/48/link-6931554_1280.png" alt="menu" width="16" height="16">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100  align-items-center">
      <div class=" d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div>
          <span class="table-header__width-ellipses pl-2">Long text included here </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="header--sort_icon"></div>
        <div class="cursor-pointer cell-header-addcol">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/01/11/21/48/link-6931554_1280.png" alt="menu" width="16" height="16">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div>
```